# Quick question: explain this typedef

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef int py_var_t (void *);
```

it is used as:

```
py_var_t *somesymbol
```

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: There is a tool that explains the declarations for a language in plain English, yet people claim that the language isn't too complicated? I'll never understand this ;) By the way, the online version of that tool is at http://www.cdecl.org/ . Just remove the `typedef` keyword to make the declaration work.

Comment: I have never, ever said that C++ was't too complicated.  C is no worse that most languages, although the declaration syntax kinda sucks.

Answer (score 22):

It defines py_var_t to be the type of a function returning int and taking a void* pointer as argument.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
typedef int py_var_t (void *);
```

defines the type of the function as described by @milan1612. Then this:

```
py_var_t *somesymbol;
```

creates a pointer to such a function. You could also have created the pointer like this:

```
int (*somesymbol)(void *);
```

but use of typedefs is better practice, particularly when the function types get more complicated.